# .recv function Socket programming TCP Server in Python

Tags: python, sockets, http, tcp, decode

Im having trouble getting my very basic and simple TCP Server to properly work with http requests. This is what I have so far

```
from socket import *
import sys 
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)


serverSocket.bind(('', 4567))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    print('Ready to serve...')
    connectionSocket, addr =  serverSocket.accept()
    print("connected from: ", addr)
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        filename = message.split()[1]                 
        f = open(filename[1:])         
        outputdata = f.read()
        connectionSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n") 
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):           
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
            connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode())
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        connectionSocket.send("file not found")
        serverSocket.close()
sys.exit()
```

The error comes from the open statement. I dont fully understand how this line of code's return value is organized.

```
message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
```

I know that the return value is in bytes but when I try to use a fuction to turn it into a string like decode() i get errors as well

I have the .py file and the html file sitting in the same directory on my local machine and the way I test this is I just run this and open up a browser and type in

```
http://127.0.0.1:4567/helloworld.html
```

My code then promptly crashes after receiving the HTTP request.
Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: " i get errors as well"  what errors?  "My code then promptly crashes after receiving the HTTP request."  do you get any indication of why it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems with your code and since you don't state what specific issues you are concerned about, here is what I see:

```
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
        connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode())
```

That appears to send a newline after every character you send back to the client.

Also, it doesn't deal with the client disconnecting because you're sending back invalid data.

Even if what you were trying to do didn't have these errors in it, you don't appear to be attempting to send back a valid http response.

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html